# Unable to use scroll bar beneath a fixed position div

Tags: html, css

There is a HTML table with a scrollbar, inside a div. There is another div with absolute position which overlaps with the table div. The problem is, table div's scroll bar is behind the absolute div (flying balloon animation), because of which I am unable to use it. Is there a way to use the scroll bar beneath the absolute div?

[image]

HTML:

```css
#parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.message {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -120px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  line-height: 115px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 60px;
  animation: move 6s infinite linear;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.message:nth-child(2) {
  left: 120px;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.message:nth-child(3) {
  left: 240px;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    bottom: -120px;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container leaderboard">
  <br>
  <p class="text-right">Logged in as <strong>{{ player.user }}</strong> <img class="" src="url" /></p>

  <div class="card">
    <h6 class="card-header text-uppercase bg-dark text-white">Leaderboard</h6>
    <div class="card-body">
      <input type="text" id="leaderboard-search" onkeyup="leaderboardSearch()" placeholder="Search for names..">

      <div class="overflow-wrap">
        <table class="table leaderboard-table table-hover sortable">
          <!-- Table here -->
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="parent">
    <div class="message" style="background-image: url(sampleurl)"></div>
    <div class="message" style="background-image: url(sampleurl)"></div>
    <div class="message" style="background-image: url(sampleurl)"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you update your snippet to demonstrate your issue ?

Comment: Please do update, your question is all about a table but your table has no relevant information to reproduce this.

Comment: I added a snippet. I want to use the scroll bar which is beneath the balloon animation.

Comment: Well if that balloon is above that table even with z-index.. you cant touch that scroll bar... you need to end your animation with that balloon away from that table or  behind that...

Comment: @EveryScreamer How can animaiton go behind and still remain visible?